# Return to previous page menu item

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, jquery

I'm wondering if someone can help me, or maybe point out a good plugin/extension.

I need a return to previous page button, but I need to insert it as a menu item, does anyone know of a way to achieve this please?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any extension that does this for you, but you can use Javascripts `history.go(-1)` feature which will do the same as clicking the "back" button on your browser.

To add a menu menu item, I would normally suggest using Joomla's Menu Manager, however it won't be the most dynamic method in your case. Therefore I'd suggest using jQuery for this, like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('.menu').prepend('<li><a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Back</a></li>');

});
```

You will of course need to change `.menu` to the class or ID that is associated with your menu's `UL` tag.

Hope this helps